Proper way to initialize an atomic variable in shared_memory
I have a portion of shared memory (a file that is created in /dev/shm and then file-mapped), and I need some synchronization between processes using it. So the memory portion have a header with an atomic variable within, and I have the problem that I'm not sure how to properly initialize the header.
NOTE: I can use C++17 at most, but in case it matters, I want to know if there's some differences between C++17 and C++20 to be aware of regarding this.
My questions are embedded in the code with comments, but in general, I'm confused about how to properly initialize shared memory.
struct header
{
    std::atomic<bool> initialized = true;
    // other fields
    std::atomic<unsigned long long> version = 0;
};

int fd = open("/dev/shm/myfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_CLOEXEC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if (fd == -1)
    throw "something";

flock(fd, LOCK_SH);

// Supose the file has space enough
void* ptr = mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
header* hdr = (header*)ptr;

// Can I read from a non-initialized atomic (even if lock-free)
// that hasn't been initialized, that is also a member of a struct
// that hasn't been initialized either (which isn't trivially 
// copyable because atomics aren't)?
// In case it's not, what can I do here?
if (!hdr->initialized) {
   flock(fd, LOCK_EXCL);

   // What are the memory order guarantees between system-calls and
   // this? Am I guaranteed that the CPU won't do the write before
   // the above `flock`?
   if (!hdr->initialized) {
      // Is this placement new defined behaviour? 
      // Could `new` require here any extra storage before `hdr`?
      // (it might happen for vectors, but I don't know what are the
      //  general guarantees)
      new (hdr) header;
   }
   
   flock(fd, LOCK_SH);
}
   
// use hdr


C++ atomics are designed for use within a single application. Your code might work by accident, but there are no guarantees if you use them for inter-process communication.

I would not know of ANY safe method to share C++ objects, because only one process can do the (in-place) new and the other process cannot cast it to an object with valid lifetime. Shared memory is for sharing data (not objects)

Have you tried sending the data over a socket/gRPC + loopback yet. It really isn't (that much) slower then using shared memory. If you still don't trust that you can still only send a synchronization signal that way.

@PepijnKramer I have added some flock calls to make sure there's only one writter at the same time.

Still, are you sure that your flock() does the right thing? Two processes could end up in the !initialized, with only one doing the init and the other one doing neither the init not the use thing -- and, if I'm reading it correctly, all processes that entered the !initialized branch will block forever, except for the one lucky enough to get the first EXCL. That process will keep a shared lock, so nobody else will get past that EXCL lock... at least not until the first one quits.

@ChristianStieber I have detached the else from the if. Besides that, there's no block forever. After the initialization, the excl lock goes back from shared. The only thing that could worry me is that the process crashes between the excl and shared lock and so I can't be sure whether about the state of the header. Is it initialized or not? That depends a lot about the particularities of how atomics and initialization interact.

You are going to need to use an OS kernel object for inter-process locking / atomic(s).

@RichardCritten Never heared of it. Any command so I can look for their man pages?

Note that, in general, I'd avoid using C++ facilities on the shared memory. Boost::interprocess doesn't even mention synchronization issues (last I looked at it, anyway) and is also full of warnings about using C++ objects in it (they do provide a smartpointer, though). C++ doesn't know about processes so mutexes and stuff may or may not work; however, Posix mutexes and stuff generally talk about "threads or processes" so you can place those into shared memory.

@ChristianStieber why do that difference matters? Aren't memory operations among processes and threads indistinguishable? I guess what matters is if they are reading the same memory or not, right?

@ABu the obvious first problem is memory addresses -- shared memory is (usually) mapped to different addresses in different processes, so pointers/references are garbage. And we don't really know whether something might have a pointer in its implementation. Also, while it probably doesn't matter for CPU instructions, we never know what OS calls might be made. And, compared to CPUs of the past, I wouldn't be surprised if CPU instructions make a difference these days. Either way, I'd recommend the safe route and only use stuff that's actually allowed to cross process boundaries.

@ChristianStieber Ok, yes of course, but I'm focusing here on primitive types and their atomic versions, not about complex data structures etc, and also focusing on memory order and initialization rules only. Everything that matters for "synchronization". To be sure about what have and doesn't have happened.

Related: C++ share atomic_int64_t between different process? The language standard does not discuss processes. But POSIX does. So you are fine as long as you know what you are doing and what's your system + language implementation. But you need to fix that deadlock discussed above by releasing the shared lock before re-locking. You need double-checked locking

@Homer512 I'm still developing the thing but as far as I read from the docs, I can "change the lock" without unlocking, to turn an excl lock to a shared one.

@ABu Yes, you can upgrade and downgrade a lock. However, you can only get an exclusive lock once all shared locks have been released. If two processes want to upgrade their shared locks to exclusive locks (because they both see the memory as uninitialized), they block each other. The kernel cannot release the shared lock of one process to grant the exclusive lock of the other

Ups, I'm wrong. The man page states that the shared lock is released prior to upgrading it. So there is no deadlock.

Sorry, I edited my comment while you were reading the old version. Yes, your code seems okay

If you don't want to use std::atomic for shared memory (it normally will work as long as you are respecting that the memory will be initialized by ftruncate() to zero), I suggest that you have a look to the compiler atomic builtins: e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html
However, I would use std::atomic and a static_assert(atomic_type::is_always_lock_free, "'atomic_type' must be lock free");
